# Change the paramaters that Visual Studio uses when running Deploy-AzureResourceGroup

Tags: powershell, azure, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to deploy resources to a resource group in Azure. This runs the 'Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1" powershell script that is automatically generated. I wanted to remove a couple of the parameters that I do not need (i.e. DSCSourceFolder) from this powershell script. When I try to deploy, it throws an error message saying that it cannot find the parameter that I removed.

```
 A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DSCSourceFolder'.
```

[image: Deploy button in Visual Studio]

Is there any way to change the default parameters that Visual Studio uses when starting the Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1 powershell script?

Comment: You can follow this guide http://rickrainey.com/2016/03/21/deploy-an-azure-resource-manage-template/

Comment: The parameters mentioned on that page are in reference to the parameters that are configured on the templates themselves. What I was referring to is the actual invocation of the Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1 script. This has a list of parameters that are automatically pulled in from somewhere in Visual Studio and I wanted to know if there was a way to edit which parameters Visual Studio uses to kick-off the main powershell script.

In [this photo](http://rickrainey.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/032116_0122_DeployanAzu12.png) you can see what I mean. '-StorageAccountName' is added by VS2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command the VS uses to invoke the script is not configurable... you can of course ignore them but not change or remove them without affecting the UI in VS.

If you just run the script from PowerShell, then you can do whatever you want to it.

All that said, I'm interested in your scenario - i.e. why the desire to customize?

Comment: Yeah that's what I decided to do - Just run it from powershell instead of using visual studio to run it. I found that I prefer this too as there are some errors that I was unable to resolve with VS since it just output a generic error message without any detail.


The reason I wanted to customize was because I wanted to use some of the variable names which are used in the parameters (i.e. $StorageAccountName) which refers to the storage account that templates are uploaded to if you're using linked templates. I also don't need a parameter like $DSCSourceFolder and wanted to remove it.

Comment: (Continued from above) - Overall, it's not a big deal at all. I only wanted to change/remove certain parameters to remove any confusion to those unfamiliar with ARM templates within visual studio.